# Sed command-- unable to remove lines beginning with word [...]

Tags: bash, unix, vim, sed

For a homework assignment, I'm trying to write a sed script that gets rid of lines beginning with the word `Today`

I used vim to make a .sed file (`q1.sed` is the name of it) and this is the command I used inside the script:

```
$ sed -n '/^Today/ d' filename
```

My instructor said he'd be using a sample .txt file to use this command on, and this is how he asked us to try running the script from inside the directory:

```
$ sed -f q1.sed samplefile.txt
```

When it generates output, the lines containing "Today" are still shown. What have I done wrong? (Is it something I did or didn't do from a command inside of my directory, or a command I fed from vim?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) file, you need to put only :

```
/^Today/d
```

Then:

```
sed -f q1.sed samplefile.txt
```

Et voilà, it works !

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered this! This worked best!

Comment: Hi, fellow Stack Overflow fan, would you like to meet up at devoxx fr? I created a chatroom for us: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/109630/devoxx-fr

Answer (score 1):

I'm not particularly familiar with the `-n` option, but with the `-e` option this works just fine:

```
Glastonbury:~ dhoelzer$ cat test.txt
Today is a test
this is a test
this is Not a Today test.
Glastonbury:~ dhoelzer$ sed -e '/^Today/d' test.txt
this is a test
this is Not a Today test.
```

To do this with a sed file, simply paste that expression into a text file:

```
/^Today/d

sed -f sendfile test.txt
```

I can't be sure, but it looks as though you've got some extra whitespace in the question, which could be the source of your problems.

Comment: OP asked to use a _sed file_

Answer (score 1):

Quite apart from the problem of putting the script into a file, your command line version

```
sed -n '/^Today/ d' filename
```

would not print anything at all, because the `-n` option prevents printing. If you wanted to use `-n`, you'd have to reverse the logic:

```
sed -n '/^Today/p' filename
```

as in "*do* print lines that *don't* start with 'Today'.

There are three main ways to run sed:

1. From the command line (or from inside a shell script), as above
2. As a script supplied to the `-f` option of sed (which is what your instructor wants). The file contains only the sed commands, in this case just the one:

   ```
   /^Today/d
   ```
3. As a stand-alone executable: if your script looks like

   ```
   #!/bin/sed -f

   /^Today/d
   ```

   you can run it directly with

   ```
   ./sedscr.sed infile
   ```

   The `/bin/sed` has to point to your sed executable.

What you did was feeding a *command* `sed -n '/^Today/ d' filename` to sed. If you did that on the command line, sed would complain; if you do it in a script supplied to `sed -f`, sed simply ignores the offending line.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged `vim`, too, then here's an example of doing that in Vim itself:

```
:g/^Today/d
```

Read more about `g` [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g).